# Calculating ΔH with non-integer coefficients in the balanced equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, combustion

I am working a practice problem out Ebbing's *General Chemistry* and for part of the problem I needed to calculate $ΔH.$ The problem considers the burning of ethane in oxygen to yield carbon dioxide and water vapor.

The coefficients used in the solution manual were 1 for ethane 7/2 for oxygen 2 for carbon dioxide and 3 for the water vapor. The coefficients I used were 2, 7, 4, and 6, respectively.

Naturally, it follows the $ΔH$ value I got is twice as large. Can anyone provide clarification here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to clarify: you determined *dimolar* enthalpy of combustion, whereas standard enthalpy of combustion is determined for a complete oxidation of *one mole* of the substance:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{C2H6(g) + 7/2 O2(g) &-> 2 CO2(g) + 3 H2O(l)} &\quad &Δ_\mathrm{c}H^\circ\\
\ce{2 C2H6(g) + 7 O2(g) &-> 4 CO2(g) + 6 H2O(l)} &\quad &Δ_\mathrm{c}H^\circ ×2
\end{align}
$$

When composing the corresponding reaction equation, make sure to balance it in such a way that the [stoichiometric number $ν$](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S06025) of the substance the enthalpy is determined for is always $-1.$

Comment: Excellent answer, andselisk, very enlightening. Thank you!